# Escape de comillas

Tags: javascript

Buen día,

Tengo un span el cual le agregué un onclick, dentro de esta función puse los siguientes datos:

```
render: function (data, display, row) {
                    console.log(row.nombre)
                    return ['<span onclick="remove(\' '+data+' \', '+row.nombre+' \',);" class = "fa fa-trash deleteButton"></span>']}
```

Al correr, y dándole clic en el icono, me sale el siguiente mensaje, dentro de la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenta varias formas de acuerdos a los ejemplos, sin embargo, aún no llego a la solución, el cual agradecería mucho de sus comentarios o referencias para poder solucionar tal inconveniente.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: La sintaxis correcta sería: `'<span onclick="remove(\''+data+'\',\''+row.nombre+'\');" class="fa fa-trash deleteButton"></span>'`

Comment: Debes usar el caracter de escape antes y después de tus 2 parámetros, también eliminar la coma final, prueba con -> `onclick="remove(\'' + data + '\', \'' + row.nombre + '\');"`

Comment: Hola que tal, antes de revisar sus comentarios llegué a la siguiente solución:<span onclick="remove(' + data + ', \' ' + row.nombre + ' \');></span>' y ya me permite en mi modal de confirmación el nombre del cliente a borrar. De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Nuevamente pongo el comentario que acabo de escribir:

Antes de revisar sus amables comentarios, estuve por decir así jugando con los caracteres, hasta que llegué a la siguiente solución:

```
'<span onclick="remove(' + data + ', \' ' + row.nombre + ' \');" class = "fa fa-trash deleteButton"></span>'
```

Adicional adjunto una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma, al eliminar un cliente, en mi modal de confirmación ya me aparece el nombre de tal cliente a eliminar.

Nuevamente agradezco los comentarios, dejo mi solución por si alguien presenta la misma situación.

Saludos.